# How can I get plain text visible in the current viewport?

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend, viewport

I want to get text that is currently (scrolled into user's view) visible in browser.

**Question 1**:
What jQuery selector or filter would do the job?

**Quesiton 2**:
I want to capture all and only the text visible to user. Even if it is a partially scrolled into screen, for example a line of text that is partially visible at bottom of viewport.
By this I also imply that we can't use capturing by whole tags, because we can't assume that whole text inside a  or  will be visible to user.

Comment: I'd say that this is most likely impossible. Just think of different platforms and browsers... If whatever you are doing requires this kind of "hack" I would advise you to reconsider it.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 you can leverage [element.scrollIntoView API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

For question 2 I'd say it's possible but would be tricky, [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) can detect whether an element is in the view or is visible and how much an element showed in the view. Based on this theoretically you can get elements' style properties like width/height/padding/line height/font-size and calculate how many characters are showing in the view